# Manual selection of custom UITableViewCell does not make the cell to be returned by tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell subclass with a switch. On the valueChanged action inside the subclass I set the **selected** property of the cell according to the switch state.

```
self.selected = self.optionSwitch.isOn
```

In the UITableViewController that handles these cells I ask the table view for the selected rows but it returns nil (no selected row).

```
self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
```

Why it returns nil if the cells are selected? I'm sure they are because I retrieved one to inspect the **selected** property and it is in fact **YES**.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
BOOL isSelected = cell.isSelected;
```

PS1: I've set the **allowsMultipleSelection** property of my table view.

PS2: I know that **tableView:selectRowAtIndexPath:** works but I didn't want to create a delegate for my custom cell just to notify the table view and make the tableview select that row.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up and used the solution in the PS2. Create a delegate for your custom cell and call the selectRowMethod.

```
#pragma mark - CellDelegate

- (void)didSelectCell:(CustomCell *)cell
{
    NSIndexPath *ip = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:ip animated:NO  scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}

- (void)didDeselectOptionCell:(CustomCell *)cell
{
    NSIndexPath *ip = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:ip animated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If by any chance someone has the same issue, here is my fix :

```
NSIndexPath *index ;
for( int i=0; i<self.slices.contains.count; i++){
    index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:index animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}
```

This will iterate over all the cell of your tableview and select them (and actually add them to the

```
tableview indexPathsForSelectedRows
```